# zero out memory in assembly

Tags: memory, assembly, arm

I'll start with the code first:

```
.equ SWI_Open, 0x66        @ open a file
.equ SWI_Close, 0x68       @ close a file
.equ SWI_PrStr, 0x69       @ Write a null-ending string
.equ SWI_RdStr, 0x6a       @ Read a string
.equ Stdout,  1            @ Set output target to be Stdout
.equ SWI_Exit, 0x11        @ Stop execution
.global _start
.text

_start:
    ldr r0,=InFileName
    mov r1,#0
    swi SWI_Open
    bcs InFileError
    ldr r1,=InFileHandle
    str r0,[r1]
    mov r8, r0      @ r8 will hold the address of the file handle
ReadLoop:
    mov r0, r8
    ldr r1, =LineArray
    mov r2, #256
    swi SWI_RdStr
    bcs EndReached
    @ r1 now has address of the read line
    mov r9, r1      @ r9 will hold the memory address of the read line
    mov r4, #0      @ r4 = START
    mov r5, #1      @ r5 = END 
    bl PerLineFunc      @ r0/r1 args passed to PerLineFunc
    @ ShuffleWord within PerLineFunc should change the words around, so now we just need to print the new line of words
    mov r0, #Stdout
    mov r1, r9
    swi SWI_PrStr
    ldr r1, =NL
    swi SWI_PrStr
    bal ReadLoop
```

SWI_RdStr reads a line from the given file and stores it into memory with the address location stored into r1. My issue is that I don't know how to zero out the memory where the line was read into. If the first line is 20 characters, and the next line is 15, then the last 5 characters of the first line are still in memory after the 2nd line is read.

I was thinking it would be something like:

```
ldr r1, =LineArray
str #0, [r1]
```

but that returns a syntax error... I'm just trying to reset the memory before running the ReadLoop again.

Edit: Posting answer in OP.
This first part needs to be added to the end of ReadLoop

```
mov r0, #0
ldr r1, =LineArray
mov r2, #0
bl EraseMemory  @ r0, r1, and r2 passed into EraseMemory
```

Here's the EraseMemory function

```
EraseMemory:
    str r0, [r1]
    add r1, r1, #4
    add r2, r2, #1
    cmp r2, #64         @ 256 / 4 = 64
    bxeq lr             @ This loop should run 64 times to erase all 256 bytes of memory that were used
    bal EraseMemory
```

Comment: fixed-insn-size RISC machines don't have room for an immediate operand and an addressing-mode + displacement in a single instruction.  Even if you don't use a displacement (`[r1 + 100]` or whatever the ARM syntax is), the store instruction encoding has meaning for the bits.  (This sort of thing is the whole point of reduced instruction-set complexity).  BTW, avoid re-loading constants when possible.  You could load `=NL` into a different reg so you wouldn't clobber `=LineArray`.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by the first part. As for the loading into registers, I was under the impression that this was ok to do since those are locations in memory. `=NL` is a different memory location than `=LineArray` so loading it into r1 isn't that big of a deal. That part of the program actually seems to work just fine, I'm just not able to wipe out the memory after I've used it

Comment: I mean you seemed to talk about loading `=LineArray` into `r1` more than once, didn't you?  I was saying you should keep `=LineArray` in a register instead of re-loading it.  Also, if `NL` is close to `LineArray` in memory, you could maybe `add  r2, r1, #(NL - LineArray)` or something.  Remember that `ldr reg, =value` is a pseudo-op that can turn into a load from a nearby constant-pool, rather than an immediate.

Comment: The first part was explaining why `str #0, [r1]` was not encodable: a `str` instruction doesn't have room for an immediate because it uses all its spare bits to encode addressing mode and displacement.  It's RISC, so the bits are just zero if there's no displacement, rather than being usable for something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to write the immediate value to a register:

```
ldr r1, =LineArray
mov r0, #0
str r0, [r1]
```

Comment: This only zeros out the first 4 bytes (the first 32 bits) of the memory at address [r1]. I need to zero out all the memory used for =LineArray

Comment: What is the size of the line ? You need to add a loop in this case.

Comment: Well the max is 256, and after seeing your first answer, I figured I would have to add a loop. I was just hoping there was an easier way with some sort of instruction that I didn't know about. Thanks for the help

Comment: There is a faster way with `stmia [rn], {r0-r3}!` where r0-r3 are pre-zeroed.  Then you can quickly clear a cache line or 4*32bits.  This is probably in-sync with DDR sizing if alignment is (sic) write.